# How to copy files from a certain range into another directory from terminal?

Tags: command-line, sudo, files, cp

I want to copy files 50,000 to 100,000 into a separate directory and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

For more context, I want to create a smaller dataset of images (50,000) from a larger one (900,000). I know that the first and last 50,000 images are all black and I don't want those ones in the small dataset.

Comment: What criteria do you use to know which 50.000 to copy?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Updated the post!

Comment: Sorted how? lexically? numerically? by timestamp?

Comment: The files in the directory are in sequential order and I want the 50,000th and 100,000th files in the new directory to be in the same order that they were in in the og directory.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this with such large numbers of files, but I'd suggest something like the following in `zsh`:

```
print -N ./*(.[50000,100000]) | xargs -r0 cp -t path/to/target/dir/
```

`./*(.)` is a qualified glob, evaluating to a list of plain files in the current directory, sorted in the lexical order determined by your locale; `[m,n]` selects a range from that list. The `-N` causes `print` to use a null separator suitable for passing to `xargs -0`

---

You can implement a similar method in shells that don't provide glob qualifiers by using an external program to filter the list - for example in `bash`:

```
printf '%s\0' ./* | sed -nz '50000,100000p' | xargs -r0 cp -t path/to/target/dir/
```

(although unlike the `zsh` version this doesn't limit the match to plain files - if that's an important distinction you could probably use extended globs to at least eliminate directory matches).